# Python: Pinpointing the Linear Part of a Slope

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have several plots that look like the following:

[image]

I am wondering what kind of methods there might be for finding the slope between approximately 5.5 and 8 for the x-axis. Where there are several plots like this, I am more so wondering if there is a way to automatically find the slope value.

Any suggestions?

I am thinking `ployfit()`, or a linear regression. The problem is that I am unsure of how to find the values automatically.

Comment: Are 5.5 and 8 fixed, or do you somehow need to find them automatically too?

Comment: c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300430/algorithm-is-there-a-linear-trend-in-data?rq=1

Comment: 5.5 and 8 are just estimates based on looking at the graph. They do show approximately where I would be looking to calculate the slope for though.

Comment: I think we need a bit more info to help you on this. What kind of data are you expecting? It's difficult to give good generic advice on curve fitting without knowing more about the characteristics of the data you're sampling. Does the data always contain a linear part of some significance?

Answer (score 42):

A generic way to find linear parts in data sets is to calculate the second derivative of the function, and see where it is (close to) zero. There are several things to consider on the way to the solution:

- How to calculate the second derivative of noisy data? One fast and simple method, that can easily be adapted to different noise levels, data set sizes and expected lengths of the linear patch, is to convolve the data with a convolution kernel equal to the second derivative of a Gaussian. The adjustable part is the width of the kernel.
- What does "close to zero" mean in your context? To answer this question, you have to experiment with your data.
- The results of this method could be used as an input to the chi^2-method described above, to identify candidate regions in the data set.

Here some source code that will get you started:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

# create theoretical data
x_a = np.linspace(-8,0, 60)
y_a = np.sin(x_a)
x_b = np.linspace(0,4,30)[1:]
y_b = x_b[:]
x_c = np.linspace(4,6,15)[1:]
y_c = np.sin((x_c - 4)/4*np.pi)/np.pi*4. + 4
x_d = np.linspace(6,14,120)[1:]
y_d = np.zeros(len(x_d)) + 4 + (4/np.pi)

x = np.concatenate((x_a, x_b, x_c, x_d))
y = np.concatenate((y_a, y_b, y_c, y_d))


# make noisy data from theoretical data
y_n = y + np.random.normal(0, 0.27, len(x))

# create convolution kernel for calculating
# the smoothed second order derivative
smooth_width = 59
x1 = np.linspace(-3,3,smooth_width)
norm = np.sum(np.exp(-x1**2)) * (x1[1]-x1[0]) # ad hoc normalization
y1 = (4*x1**2 - 2) * np.exp(-x1**2) / smooth_width *8#norm*(x1[1]-x1[0])



# calculate second order deriv.
y_conv = np.convolve(y_n, y1, mode="same")

# plot data
plt.plot(x,y_conv, label = "second deriv")
plt.plot(x, y_n,"o", label = "noisy data")
plt.plot(x, y, label="theory")
plt.plot(x, x, "0.3", label = "linear data")
plt.hlines([0],-10, 20)
plt.axvspan(0,4, color="y", alpha=0.2)
plt.axvspan(6,14, color="y", alpha=0.2)
plt.axhspan(-1,1, color="b", alpha=0.2)
plt.vlines([0, 4, 6],-10, 10)
plt.xlim(-2.5,12)
plt.ylim(-2.5,6)
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image]

`smooth_width` is the width of the convolution kernel. In order to adjust the amount of noise, change the value `0.27` in random.normal to different values. And please note, that this method does not work well close to the border of the data space.

As you can see, the "close-to-zero" requirement for the second derivative (blue line) holds quite well for the yellow parts, where the data is linear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you refer me some articles where I can understand why convoluting a noisy data with the second derivative of gaussian functions returns the smoothened second derivative of the noisy function?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Ramer Douglas Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to simplify your data to a smaller set of line segments. The algorithm allows you to specify an `epsilon` such that every data point will be no farther than `epsilon` from some line segment. The slope of the line segments would give a rough estimate of the slope of the curve.

There is a [Python implementation of the RDP algorithm here.](https://github.com/sebleier/RDP/)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a possible solution, it will find the straight line segment of the points which has the minimum chi^2 value that's longer than a preset minimum;

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from numpy import pi, sin, linspace, exp, polyfit
from matplotlib.mlab import stineman_interp

x = linspace(0,2*pi,20);
y = x + sin(x) + exp(-0.5*(x-2)**2);

num_points = len(x)

min_fit_length = 5

chi = 0

chi_min = 10000

i_best = 0
j_best = 0

for i in range(len(x) - min_fit_length):
    for j in range(i+min_fit_length, len(x)):

        coefs = polyfit(x[i:j],y[i:j],1)
        y_linear = x * coefs[0] + coefs[1]
        chi = 0
        for k in range(i,j):
            chi += ( y_linear[k] - y[k])**2

        if chi < chi_min:
            i_best = i
            j_best = j
            chi_min = chi
            print chi_min

coefs = polyfit(x[i_best:j_best],y[i_best:j_best],1)
y_linear = x[i_best:j_best] * coefs[0] + coefs[1]


fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,'ro')
ax.plot(x[i_best:j_best],y_linear,'b-')


show()
```

[image]

i can see it getting problematic for larger data sets though...

Answer (score 0):

If your "model" of the data consists of data that mostly fits a straight line, with a few outliers or wiggly bits at the end, you could try the [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) algorithm.

The (very wordy, sorry) pseudocode here would be:

```
choose a small threshold distance D

for N iterations:
    pick two random points from your data, a and b
    fit a straight line, L, to a and b
    count the inliers: data points within a distance D of the line L
    save the parameters of the line with the most inliers so far

estimate the final line using ALL the inliers of the best line
```