# Algorithm to make a polynomial fit of a part of a data set

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem of algorithm. I don't know if stackoverflow is the right place to post it but since I use matlab and want to do this with it, I post it there.
My problem is the following : I have a set of data and I do not know much about it except the fact that at the end of this set, the points have to be quite linear. I want to make a linear fit of these points that are linearly distributed without using the part that is not.

(an image is always better to understand) :[image]

As you see there, I have the blue data, that is not linear but that has a linear part at the end (red part). What I would want, is to find an algorithm that allows me to know when the behaviour of the data curve ends its linearity.

I don't know if I'm clear ?

I've tried by taking a few points at the right and make a linear fit of those few points. Then add some points to the few and check if those are "near enough" of the linear fit. Then make once more a linear fit with the added points and so on but I think it's not the best solution because the "first" points have lot of noise (which is not represented here on the image)...

Do you have any idea or proposition or link ?

Thank you !

Comment: will it always become almost linear in the end? or you're interested in the longest straight line in any segment?

Comment: @Fallen I'm not sure that it will always do so, but I think that in most cases, it will be quite linear. What do you mean by 'the longest straight line in any segment'?

Comment: I mean are you interested in the only straight line segment that ends at the last input of data?

Comment: @Fallen No, I don't. I only want the fit, it has not to pass by the last point.

Comment: This data looks logistic with an additional linear trend.

Comment: @A.Webb This is only an example. My data is not like that. It was only to give a shape and to be clear :)
This curve is simply atan(x-b)+a*(x-b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I would want, is to find an algorithm that allows me to know when the behaviour of the data curve ends its linearity.

Linear data has a particularly nice property, it has constant slope. The second derivative of a linear section should be approximately zero.

Use a spline fit (with some kind of smoothing if the data is noisy) to get a continuous version of your data, call it `g(x)`. When `g''(x) ~ 0`, i.e. when the second derivative is small, this is a linear section.

Comment: Indeed, it is; and it can be done pretty efficiently. You don't even need to convert the data to continuous. [You can compute the second derivative of the discrete data,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) and then search for areas where second derivative lies within a small threshold. Here's another SO question with this exact algorithm implemented in Python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691775/python-pinpointing-the-linear-part-of-a-slope

Comment: @darksky Thank you a lot.
Here are my results http://stackoverflow.com/q/17652128/2320757
. As you can see, I faced another problem. If you have time, could you check it ? :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Snippet your data set by x-position and then set some cutoff for linearity.

- Start at one end
- Check the pearson correlation coefficient of the next predefined portion of the graph
- If above a certain threshold add the included portion of x to your range, otherwise stop there

Alternately you could do a check for linear being the best fit of a number of polynomial fittings. For that I would:

- Define a few generic functions of order 1-n where n is pretty small (maybe 3)
- Add data points to linear testing set
- Compare least squares value of your n functions
- If linear has the lowest least squares value, or is within some distance of the minimum of your n function continue adding points. Otherwise stop and say that the function was linear before the last addition.

Those are at least pretty straightforward ways of doing it, and in my Occam's razor mind they also have the lowest complexity (n*curve-fit complexity in both cases, though the second one has a bigger constant.), though it's very possible that there lower complexity algorithms out there.

Comment: I will try this but it's quite the same as I previously did. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mwoua you could also recurse at non-linear portions and get all linear portions, but I'm not sure if that's valuable to you.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to approximate it with 2-polynomial with more and more points from right to left and watch for the third coefficient. As it stays small enough, the distribution is linear enough as well.

The thing is it is hard to establish "small enough" in numbers other then empirically.

The other way might be comparison of linear approximation over the real data. The same way adding points from right to left measuring approximation standart deviation. As soon as it is satisfactory, the approximation is good and the data might be concidered linear.

And that's a little better, because the deviation is quite a transparent concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you have piecewise linear behavior with abrupt transitions, you could try a fit of the form

```
E[Y] = b0 + b1 * x + b2 * I + b3 * x * I
```

where I is an [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) that's 1 when some condition is met and 0 otherwise.  For your example, the condition could be `x > 0`.  The `b2` coefficient would capture the vertical displacement if the two segments are parallel, while the `b3` term is an "interaction" that would capture slope variations on either side of the indicator breakpoint.

If the transition is more gradual, as you've drawn it, then I agree with @A.Webb's comment about logistic with trend.