# Algorithm to detect a linear behaviour in a data set

Tags: matlab

I have posted a question about an [Algorithm to make a polynomial fit of a part of a data set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17595932/2320757) some time ago and received some propositions to do what I wanted. But I face another problem now I try to apply the ideas suggested in the answers.
My goal was to find the best linear fit of a data set, in which only a part of it was linear.

Here is an example of what I must do :[image: Data sets]

We have these two data sets, and I must make a linear trend of the linear part of the data that is at the left of the dashed line. In red, we have the ideal data set, that has a linear part from the beginning until the dashed line. In blue, we have the 'problematic' data set, that has a plateau. The bold part is the part that I have to use to do the linear fit of the data.

My problem is that I tried to do as mentionned in the question linked above : I found the second order derivative of the smoothed data and looked when it was not 'close enough' of 0. But here are my results for the problematic data set (first image) and for the ideal data set (second image) :

[image]
[image]

(Sorry for quality, I don't know why it is so blurred)
On both images, I plotted the first order derivative and in red, the second order derivative. On the first image, we see peaks of second derivative values. But the problem is that the peaks are not very 'high', making it difficult to establish a threshold that would tell if the set is linear or not... On the contrary, the peak of the first derivative is quite high, making it easy to see visually.

I thought that calculate the mean of the values of the first derivative and look when the value differ too much from the mean value would be enough... But when I take the mean of the values of the first derivative in order to see where the values differ from the mean value, there is a sort of offset due to the peak.

How to remove this offset in order to take only the mean value of the data *at the right* (the data at the left of the discontinuity that is seen on Image 1 could be non linear or be linear but have a different value from the values at the right!) of the peak efficiently ?

Comment: How do you compute your derivatives? Numeric differentiation adds a lot of noise if not done correctly. I'd first smooth the original data (using a suitable low-pass filter), then interpolate it using splines and then take the derivatives of the splines. That should give you a much smoother derivative approximation in which your peaks should be easier to detect.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker, I can do it with two methods. The first one (the one I used to make these figures) is by estimating the derivatives with something like 
`dy = diff(smooth(y));dx = diff(x);dydx = dy./dx; dx2 = (dx(1:end-1)+dx(2:end))/2; d2ydx2 = diff(dydx)./dx2;`
The second one is the method you just mentionned. Bizarrely, the first method gives better results...

Comment: It seems you know the endpoint of interest. Hence it should be better to simply take the endpoint instead of the mean. Possibly smooth the data a bit before taking the endpoint. --- Furthermore, also make sure your algorithm handels linear regions with a trend in the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mean` operator (as you have noticed) is **very** sensitive to outliers (peaks). You may wish to use more robust estimators, such as the `median` or the x-percentile of the values (which should be more appropriate for your case).