# Find "anomalous" curves in a "generic-linear" shape

Tags: python, math, gis, linear-algebra

I am not a mathematician but I am pretty sure my problem could be solved with a bit (maybe a lot?) of good maths.

Let me explain the problem with a picture.

[image]

I have a network (GIS data) which is composed of many linear segments.
Rarely, a curve is present throughout these segments and I would need to find a reasonable method to detect them rather automatically.

Given that I have the coordinates of my segments and the curves (the green dots in the picture), would you reccomend a reasonable way to detect these curves?

I am not sure but it could be similar to the opposite of what is asked in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691775/python-pinpointing-the-linear-part-of-a-slope), but I don't actually have a function to calculate a second derivative, only line segments (and curves) made by vertices...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can easily list out the points in a segment and iterate over them, and that a segment is "mostly" linear, you can take the end-points of a segment and interpolate a line between them.

Next, [check if each point of the segment lies on the interpolated line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255120/determining-if-a-point-lies-on-a-particular-slope-between-two-points) and add a margin of error.

You can then assume that several adjacent points of the segment that do not lie on the interpolated line make up a curve.

You may need to implement other checks:

- Are the end-points are part of a straight segment -- i.e. that the segment does not end in a curve
- Does the segment bend and should the segment be treated as two segments?
- Can two curves be adjacent to one another without a point between them that's on the line?

To get started with python, I'd write the function `is_on_line` and loop over all the points, calling it each time to see if the point is on the line.

Excuse the verbose pseudo code (makes lots of assumptions about data structures, can be done in one loop), but this should help you break the problem apart to get started:

```
points_on_line = []
for idx, point in enumerate(segment):
    result = is_on_line(
        endpoint_1_x=segment[0].x,
        endpoint_1_y=segment[0].y,
        endpoint_2_x=segment[-1].x,
        endpoint_2_y=segment[-1].y,
        coord_x=point.x,
        coord_y=point.y,
        error_margin=0.1,
    )
    points_on_line.append((point, result,))

for point, on_line in points_on_line:
    # figure out where your curves are
```